# d3.js labelled horizontal bar chart but giving it animation capabilities

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created various vertical bar charts - but need to rejig this to work in horizontal mode.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmJzXZ

//static vertical chart
http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/201/

//animated vertical chart
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/12073/

this will swap the axis around.

```
  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(y);
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(x);
```

but may also need to need rebuild it to look like the following wireframe concept

[image]

```
   var data = [{
            "name": "Apples",
            "value": 20,
    },
        {
            "name": "Bananas",
            "value": 12,
    },
        {
            "name": "Grapes",
            "value": 19,
    },
        {
            "name": "Lemons",
            "value": 5,
    },
        {
            "name": "Limes",
            "value": 16,
    },
        {
            "name": "Oranges",
            "value": 26,
    },
        {
            "name": "Pears",
            "value": 30,
    }];

    //sort bars based on value
    data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value);
    })

    //set up svg using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
    var margin = {
        top: 15,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 15,
        left: 60
    };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .3)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

    //make y axis to show bar names
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        //no tick marks
        .tickSize(0)
        .orient("right");

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bars")


    //append rects
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name);
        })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.value);
        });

    //add a value label to the right of each bar
    bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.value) + 3;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        });

    var labels =         
        bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 - 30;
        })
    .attr("x", 0)
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A fully responsive horizontal bar chart is given here with labels on the side and animation effect:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100},
    width = parseInt(d3.select("#chart").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = parseInt(d3.select("#chart").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], 0.1);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var dollarFormatter = d3.format(",.0f")

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return dollarFormatter(d);});

var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var data = [
  {
    "metric": "Sales",
    "Name": "Pears",
    "total": 2020.161
  },
  {
    "metric": "Sales",
    "Name": "Apples",
    "total": 2122.545
  },
  {
    "metric": "Sales",
    "Name": "Bananas",
    "total": 4154.9
  }];


  // Filter to select a subset
  var subset = data.filter(function(el){
    return  (el["metric"]);
  });

  // Sort the data so bar chart is sorted in decreasing order
  subset = subset.sort(function(a, b) { return a["total"] - b["total"]; });

  yScale.domain(subset.map(function(d) { return d["Name"]; }));
  xScale.domain([0, d3.max(subset, function(d) { return d["total"]; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .append("text")

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(subset)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      //.attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d["Name"]); })
      //.attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())      
   .attr("width", 0)
   .transition()
   .duration(500)
   .delay(function(d,i){ return i*250})
      .attr("width", function(d){
            return xScale(d["total"]);
      });

    setTimeout(function(){
    d3.selectAll("rect").transition()
    .duration(500)
    .delay(function(d,i){ return 250*(3-i);})
    .attr("width",function(d){ return 0;})
    },2000);

// Define responsive behavior
function resize() {
  var width = parseInt(d3.select("#chart").style("width")) - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = parseInt(d3.select("#chart").style("height")) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Update the range of the scale with new width/height
  xScale.range([0, width]);
  yScale.rangeRoundBands([height, 0], 0.1);

  // Update the axis and text with the new scale
  svg.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .select(".label")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + margin.bottom / 1.5 + ")");

  svg.select(".y.axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Update the tick marks
  xAxis.ticks(Math.max(width/75, 2), " $");

  // Force D3 to recalculate and update the line
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return xScale(d["total"]); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d["Name"]); })
    .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand());
};

// Call the resize function whenever a resize event occurs
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);

// Call the resize function
resize();

// Define the format function
function format(d) {
  d.total = +d.total;
  return d;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);body{font-family:Karla!important}.bar{fill:#c7003b}.bar:hover{fill:#61001d}.axis{font-size:10px}.axis line,.axis path{fill:none;stroke:#D4D8DA;stroke-width:1px;shape-rendering:crispEdges}.x path{display:none}#chart{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute}.d3-tip{line-height:1;font-size:14px;padding:12px;background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);color:#b9b9b9;border-radius:2px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>


<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

You can use the above as a base and then change it accordingly. The main code for the animation is:

```
                .transition()
                .duration(1500)
                .delay(function(d,i){ return i*250})
    .attr("width", function(d){
        return scale(d.value);
    });
```

Comment: sure - but its not animated and doesn't resemble the new design

Comment: @TheOldCounty You can try something like this. Do you want the animation to apply every x seconds?

Comment: The codes above should be useful. You have a responsive horizontal bar chart. From the second code (or even your jsfiddle with the animation) you can take the elements you need for the animation (delay is one of the tags included).

Comment: Just general animation capabilities - it needs to look like the design

Comment: @TheOldCounty The widget has everything now. You can adjust it :)

Comment: @TheOldCounty Did that work? I believe the answer is correct. In case you need additional things, please raise it.

Comment: It doesn't match the design requirements - also the animation is to have the bars grow towards their end points

Comment: @TheOldCounty What you are trying to do is in this answer. You can change the code accordingly. Basically, in questions here, you need to show an effort. It seems that you have not understood what the code does. I can try later changing this line for you. But it should be easy for you as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this,
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyJPby

```
   var data = [{
            "name": "Apples",
            "value": 20,
    },
        {
            "name": "Bananas",
            "value": 12,
    },
        {
            "name": "Grapes",
            "value": 19,
    },
        {
            "name": "Lemons",
            "value": 5,
    },
        {
            "name": "Limes",
            "value": 16,
    },
        {
            "name": "Oranges",
            "value": 26,
    },
        {
            "name": "Pears",
            "value": 30,
    }];

    //sort bars based on value
    data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value);
    })

    //set up svg using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
    var margin = {
        top: 15,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 15,
        left: 60
    };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .1)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

    //make y axis to show bar names
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        //no tick marks
        .tickSize(0)
        .orient("left");

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    //append rects
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name);
        })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.value);
        });

    //add a value label to the right of each bar
    bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.value) + 3;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        });
```

from here
https://bl.ocks.org/hrecht/f84012ee860cb4da66331f18d588eee3

Comment: need to build on top of what I had - but also retain some of the animation properties as well as remodel it with the label above the bars as per wireframe